# vectorize this double-loop nest over all matrix elements with 'if ... else ..."

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

We are given the following R code which iterates through every row and column of matrix `A`, and if the value is positive, it saves it as is in matrix, and if it is negative, the calculate the exponential value minus 1.

```
qFunc1 <- function(A) {

if (!is.matrix(A) || !is.numeric(A))
    stop("A must be numeric matrix")

B <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))

for (i in seq_len(nrow(A)))
{
    for (j in seq_len(ncol(A)))
    {
        if (!is.na(A[i, j]))
        {
            if (A[i, j] > 0)
                B[i, j] <- A[i, j]
            else
                B[i, j] <- exp(A[i, j]) - 1
        }
    }
}

B
}
```

This code gives the correct result but we are asked to "vectorize" the loop-nest with a one-liner, which I don't know how. The "if ... else ..." in another "if" makes me struggle.

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

Note that I am not allowed to use any `*apply` functions as they are not "vectorized".

Comment: Something like that I think. `A <- matrix(rnorm(16),4,4) `. `t(apply(A,1,function(x) ifelse(x>0,x,exp(x)-1)))`. Bear in mind underneath a one liner there are codes. So your function is a one liner. :-).

Comment: This is great but unfortunately I am not allowed to use any apply-like function... This is what's giving me problems.... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the one-liner requirement I would do

```
B <- A                        ## initialize the output matrix
ind <- (!is.na(A)) & (A <= 0) ## a logical matrix
B[ind] <- exp(A[ind]) - 1     ## update the output matrix
```

With the one-liner requirement I would do

```
B <- ifelse((!is.na(A)) & (A <= 0), exp(A) - 1, A)
```

---

Here is a quick test.

```
set.seed(0)
A <- round(matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5), 2)  ## create a 5 x 5 matrix
A[sample.int(length(A), 5)] <- NA       ## set 5 NA
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,]  1.26    NA  0.76 -0.41 -0.22
#[2,] -0.33 -0.93    NA  0.25  0.38
#[3,]  1.33 -0.29 -1.15    NA  0.13
#[4,]  1.27 -0.01 -0.29  0.44  0.80
#[5,]  0.41    NA -0.30    NA -0.06

## use your original function
B1 <- qFunc1(A)

## one-liner "vectorization"
B2 <- ifelse((!is.na(A)) & (A <= 0), exp(A) - 1, A)

## check that they give identical results
all.equal(B1, B2)
#[1] TRUE
```